# React form is submitting twice without e.preventDefault() and zero times with e.preventDefault()

Tags: reactjs, forms, events, submit

below code results in 2 submissions. If I add onSubmit={e => { e.preventDefault();} }, to the form, there will be zero submission:

```
export default function SearchBar() {
  return (
    <div>
      <form
        action={BackEnd_ServerName + "/xyz"}
        method="GET"            
      >
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder=""
          name="frontEnd_searchBox"
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export default function SearchBar() {
  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder=""
          name="frontEnd_searchBox"
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Try this

Comment: this is fine, but I need to send the inputed text to the backend and show the result from the backend too. is there a better way to do that?

Comment: use onChange in input field and call that function

`onChange=this.changeHandler`